# Express an exponential integral in hypergeometric form

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, exponentiation, hypergeometric-function

I am new to hypergeometric function. I am trying to express this:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^k+bx}dx$$

in a hypergeometric form.
I have read some reference, but I don't get it how to cope with this one.
thanks for your help!!

Comment: anyone please  ?

Comment: Expand either $e^{-ax^k}$ or $e^{bx}$ into its well-known Taylor series, and exchange the order of summation and integration.

Comment: hi, I have tried to expand two of them.If I expand $e^{-ax^k}$, it will result like: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-ak)^n}{n!}b^{-nk-1}\Gamma(nk+1)$, the result is a liitle higher than the simulation result.If I expand exp(-bx), the result will diverge. Maybe I cannot change the order of summation and integration?

Comment: *If I expand $exp(-bx)$, the result will diverge.* - No, it doesn't. It converges unconditionally for all $k>1$, and for $k=1$ if $a>b^k$. We have $\displaystyle\int=\frac1k\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac nk\bigg)}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\bigg(\frac b{\sqrt[k]a}\bigg)^n.$

Comment: Actually, that's $a>|b|^k$ and $\dfrac1{k\beta}\cdot\displaystyle\sum$

Comment: Oh,the k is less than 1 in my case.Does it still converge unconditionally?

Comment: If $k<1$, then the integral only converges for negative values of *b*. But, if this is so, then just expand $\exp\Big(-ax^k\Big)$ into its Taylor series, since $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty P(x)~e^{bx}$ converges for all polynomials *P*, if $b<0$.

Comment: thanks! I have found my mistakes.I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it, and accept it, so that the question may not clog up the *Unanswered Questions Queue*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to expand $e^{-ax^b}$ first, and finally I get an answer like:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-a^n}{n!} \left(b\right)^{-nk-1}\Gamma(nk+1)$.

this answer is ok for k <1.